# Trying to get property of non-object -> xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, object

I'm retrieving an xml:

```
$xml = file_get_contents($query);

echo $xml->Email;
echo $xml[0]->Email;
```

The xml (echo $xml) looks like this:

```
<GetUserInfo>
<Customer>TestUser</Customer>
<Email>test@test.com</Balance>
</GetUserInfo>
```

But both those approaches give the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 86

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 87
```

How can I get the value of Email and Customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns the file content, not an object. You can only use [`preg_match`](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php) if you want to stick to string content (**totally not advised**):

```
preg_match('~<Email>([^<]+)</Email>~i', file_get_contents($__filePath__), $emails);
```

I recommend using [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) (code not tested):

```
$XMLDoc = new DOMDocument();
$XMLDoc->load($__filePath__);
$XPath = new DOMXPath($XMLDoc);
$emails = $XPath->query('//email');
foreach ($emails as $email)
    var_dump($email->nodeValue);
```

You might use another Xpath expression like `//email[1]` or `/GetUserInfo/Email`
The foreach may also be replaced by `$email = reset($emails);` if you only want the first mail.

Comment: Totally not advised, but here it is and look how easy it is. =) Love it

Answer (score 3):

Your `$xml` is a string. `$xml->` accesses a property of an object. That is not compatible. A php string is not an object.

You may want to use `var_dump()` instead of `echo()` to see all the details of your variables.

A simple string to object convertor is `simplexml_load_string()`

```
$xml='
<GetUserInfo>
<Customer>TestUser</Customer>
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
</GetUserInfo>
';

var_dump($xml);
$Xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($Xml);
echo($Xml->Email);
```